# MVVM : Binding external object property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a rather simple case but I can't get the correct solution to it.
On my MVVM application, I would like my `MainView` (attached to `MainViewModel`)  to display **current user logon** (name) through binding.

`User` class is a POCO implementing INPC. The `CurrentUser` instance is a **static** property of my application controller `AppController`. The `LogOn`
property is the string I want to display in `MainView`.

So short version :  I want to bind `AppController.CurrentUser.LogOn` in `MainView`.

I tried several ways of static binding (like in [this article](http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/09/28/wpf-4-5-%E2%80%93-part-9-binding-to-static-properties/) ), I can't get it to work.

Any idea of out to make this work ?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

The problem is that initial binding works, but when I set another User object to current user , the LogOn property is not refreshed, even though `AppControl.CurrentUser`  property raises a static event PropertyChanged.

**EDIT 2**

I tried @Henk Holterman solution (echo property from ViewModel) ,and debugging it I found the trick :In fact , the problem was a race condition : my ViewModel was raising the UserChanged event through an EventAggregator , and then raises PropertyChanged , but it was too quick and object reference was not changed on AppController when event raises.

Thank you very much all for your help !

Comment: Does the LogOn property notify that is has been changed, (i.e. calls OnNotifyPropertyChanged in its setter)?

Comment: More importantly - does the `AppController.CurrentUser` (potentially) change while `MainView` is loaded?

Comment: `{Binding LogOn, Source={x:Static local:AppController.CurrentUser}}` should work.

Comment: an you should be sure, that AppController.CurrentUser is set before the View is loaded! Because CurrentUser is a static member, it cannot raise PropertyChanged event.

Comment: You could also echo the property as `MainViewModel.CurrentUser`, no need for the View to know what your deeper architecture is.

Comment: @Alex yes, LogOn implements by inheriting BaseINPC [https://pastebin.com/ratEvS6z] (BaseINPC)   [https://pastebin.com/VgESGyCP] (User class)

Comment: OK I missed a part of my explanation ; editing the description

Comment: @Ivoros There is `StaticPropertyChanged` since WPF 4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AppController class may look like this:

```
public class User
{
    public string LogOn { get; set; }
}

public static class AppController
{
    public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler StaticPropertyChanged;

    private static User currentUser;
    public static User CurrentUser
    {
        get { return currentUser; }
        set
        {
            currentUser = value;
            StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(CurrentUser)));
        }
    }
}
```

Then the Binding might be written like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(local:AppController.CurrentUser).LogOn}"/>
```